# How to fix 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous' in Python produced after comparing simple data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

after getting data of the Bitcoin (BTC-USD) from Yahoo, I try to create a new column to show if the Close price is higher than the Open price of of each day.

What I want to do is to create a column that shows 1 when the Close is higher than the Open. And a 0 when that condition is not true.

When I try to compare the Close and the Open values I receive the next message : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have tried several things to fix it (like importing the data as a CSV instead directly from Yahoo) but unfortunately I couldn't find the solution.

Below you can see the code that I am using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
df = dr.data.get_data_yahoo('btc-usd',start = '01-01-2015', end= '31-12-2018')
df.head(2)

df['X'] = [1 if (df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'Open'])  else 0 for ei in df.index] #---> The error is produced in this line of code
df.tail()
```

Below you can see the error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-eb64775bf24f> in <module>
----> 1 df['X'] = [1 if (df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'Open'])  else 0 for ei in df.index]
      2 df.tail()

<ipython-input-45-eb64775bf24f> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df['X'] = [1 if (df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'Open'])  else 0 for ei in df.index]
      2 df.tail()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1477                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1478                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1479 
   1480     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would like to get the result of this formula. Having 1 when the Close is > Open and 0 when the conditional is false.

Comment: I believe that the issue is that one of the .loc statements is returning multiple values when it should be returning one. I'd manually print them out and find which one is making an error.

Comment: The issue is that logic statements in pandas expected all values being compared to have the same shape. Example: (1 or 15) is a valid statement, but (1 or [1, 2]) is not valid. The way to fix this is to either change the way your DF sorta the Close column, or to use one of the operators mentioned in the error (.any(), .all(), etc.).

Comment: Huh that sounds odd. Then I would wrap that statement in parentheses and add ".any()" or ".all()" to the end. Since there is just one value each, then adding that phrase to the end wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried it and everything seems correct. For example, if I print, print(df['Close']) the first value is 314.890015 and if I print, print(df['Open']) the first value is 318.239990. The weird thing is that when I try to compare those two values is when I receive the above message...

Comment: Thank you! You are right the issue can be solved adding .all() to this expression: (df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'Open']).all() I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the series comparison outside of the list comprehension, like this:

```
df['X'] = 1*(df['Close'] > df['Open'])
```

It'll work. The series comparison returns a series with True/False values. You can multiply the True by 1 to obtain your desired result.

If you need a more complicated function, you can use an `.apply` on the `df['Close'] > df['Open']` series (I'll show it with simple 1/0 but you can pick it up from there):

```
df['X'] = (df['Close'] > df['Open']).apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Itamar, It worked correctly! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3666197 you're not wrong, but as long as we're talking about Community Etiquette, do you think that your phrasing is appropriate for a new user with (apparently) no bad intent?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin - may be yes, maybe not, English is not my first foreign language. Would you, kindly enlighten me, what do you consider yourself perhaps being on or might be behind a fuzzy edge of appropriateness of wording, as you have reflected your concern, expressed above? Thank you for helping me better understand your view and to further modify my style of phrasing, if you would decide to share details on your opinion on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place 1 in a column when Close > open just use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
df['X'] = np.where(df['Close']>df['Open'],1,0)
```

second solution could be

```
df['X'] = 0
df.loc[df['Close']>df['Open'],"X"] = 1
print(df)
```

```
                 High   Low          Open       Close        Volume     Adj Close   X
Date                            
2014-12-31  319.089996  308.890015  311.269989  318.239990  6472822    318.239990   1
2015-01-01  321.359985  313.540009  318.239990  314.890015  4073067    314.890015   0
2015-01-02  316.399994  313.079987  314.890015  315.209991  4673971    315.209991   1
2015-01-03  315.829987  284.890015  315.209991  287.130005  14209564    287.130005  0
2015-01-04  289.940002  255.869995  287.130005  264.720001  24255392    264.720001  0
```

Comment: Thank you as well Tawad. This solution also solve the problem!